# How to add a VSTS group by default to every new project?

Tags: azure-devops

I have created an `Engineering group` comprising of developers within the organization. I would like to add that group to every project whenever a new project is created.

[image]

How can I get that done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, there has no such settings to add an account level group to each project automatically.

I added an user voice [Enable to add a security group for all projects (account level)](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/33178264-enable-to-add-a-security-group-for-all-projects-a) to suggest this feature, you can vote and follow up.

If you create an account level group and want to use it for all projects, the workaround for now is adding the group to each project manually.

[image]

Comment: User Voice no longer exists, but the suggestion was migrated to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365872/enable-to-add-a-security-group-for-all-projects-ac.html?inRegister=true